# Information not being sent to personal email address when I click send

Tags: php, html

I Was doing some research on YouTube to help me do a form for a website I am working on. The goal is to have the form send the information to my personal email address when the person submits the form. Here is a test run I am doing but when I press send form I am not receiving anything from my personal email address.

Thank you.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">


</head>
<body>
<main>
    <p>Send email</p>
    <form class="contact-form" action="contactform.php" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="full name"><br>
          <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="your email"><br>
          <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="subject"><br>
          <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="full name"><br>
       <textarea name="message" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea><br>
        <button type="submit" name="submit0 ">SEND MAIL</button>
    </form>
    </main>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$name = $_POST['name'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$mailFROM = $_POST ['mail'];
$message = $_POST ['message'];

$to_email= "kenneth2461@hotmail.com";
$headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;

$txt = "You have received an email from ".$name.".\n\n".$message;

mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers);

header("Location: index.html?mailsend");
}
?>
</body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Have you checked your spam folder?

Comment: @MuhammadUmair Yes I did and haven't seen anything in there either